# Is this a good way to change component values in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a page with a component. I want to be able to give the component custom values based on the data. If we look at this screen shot

[2 components here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFVB5.png)

There are 2 of the same components being called. The top has a key with values and the bottom is a key with values. The top component Submitted has a value of 50, while the bottom component Submitted has 100.

It will update by retrieving data from somewhere ( haven't thought where yet but it definitely wont be hard coded ).

This is how I have that component set up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'



export class SwatchElement extends Component {
    constructor(props){   
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            Submitted: this.props.Submitted, // Submitted : this.props.Submitted 
            Redeemed: 50,
            PaymentInProgress: 85,
            PaymentFailed:25,
            Settled:60,
            Expired:10,
        }
        }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div class="list-container">
                  <ul class="swatch">
                      <li class="swatch__elem" name="Submitted">Submitted <span class="used-space">{this.state.Submitted}</span></li>
                      <li class="swatch__elem" name="Redeemed">Redeemed <span class="used-space">{this.state.Redeemed}</span></li>
                      <li class="swatch__elem" name="Payment Inprogress">Payment Inprogress <span class="used-space">{this.state.PaymentInProgress}</span></li>
                      <li class="swatch__elem" name="Payment Failed">Payment Failed <span class="used-space">{this.state.PaymentFailed}</span></li>
                      <li class="swatch__elem" name="Settled">Settled <span class="used-space">{this.state.Settled}</span></li>
                      <li class="swatch__elem" name="Expired" style={{paddingrRight: '15px'}}>Expired <span class="used-space">{this.state.Expired}</span></li>

                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SwatchElement
```

Now when I want to change the values I assigned values like this in the parent component

```
<div class="row">
              <SwatchElement Submitted={x}/>
              <SwatchElement Submitted={100}/>
          </div>
```

It looks like its doing what I want it to do but I don't know if this would be the right way to do it. Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest that you use the Submitted value directly from the props rather than assigning it to the state first: `<li class="swatch__elem" name="Submitted">Submitted <span class="used-space">{this.props.Submitted}</span></li>`

Comment: @delis awesome, so I was close , instead of using state just use props directly. Tested it and its working, this seems like the best way to do this. Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome @jfishdiuahk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach:

```
 this.state = {
            Submitted: this.props.Submitted, // Submitted : this.props.Submitted 
            Redeemed: 50,
            PaymentInProgress: 85,
            PaymentFailed:25,
            Settled:60,
            Expired:10,
 }
```

has one drawback, try to change `the props.Submitted` *after* the component has rendered, you will see still old value, because the component constructor runs *once* when the component is created. Hence when the component is *updated* there is no place in your code, where the new props would get copied to state.

If you don't care that props get updated, you can leave it like that.

If you do care about updated props, there are ways to do it, but it is generally [recommended](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) to avoid using derived state. Using derived state can be tricky because you must synchronize the state with the props, so one way is to avoid copying the props to state altogether (if that's possible) and use props directly; e.g. use `this.props.Submitted` in render.

Comment: by using props directly I switched it from this.state.Submitted to this.props.Submitted. This should work without the problem mentioned in your comment right?

Comment: @jfishdiuahk Yeah because that way you are always reading fresh data.

Comment: going to mark it as accepted answer, is the constructor pointless in the swatch component then? Because I removed submitted from the constructor and it still worked.

Comment: @jfishdiuahk it depends if you are using `this.props.Submitted` in render you can remove line where you copied that to state from constructor.